# mvc: private in Service & Autowired

Tags: spring-mvc

I have 2 layers from Controller->Service made in MVC Spring 3 design. Also I have somes privates in the service.
Now, my question is, since the default scope is defined as Singleton, are they thread-safe?

Here is the code look like:

StatController.java:

```
// statics
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/stat")
public class StatController {
    @Autowired
    private StatManager statManager;
    ...
}
```

StatManager.java

```
public interface StatManager {
    public File statExec(StatCriteria criteria) throws IOException;
}
```

StatManagerImpl.java

```
@Service("statManager")
public class StatManagerImpl implements StatManager {
    private Hashtable<Long, Result> hashtableResult = null;

    private void initialization() {
         this.hashtableResult  = null;
         // ....
    }

    @Override
    public File statExec(StatCriteria criteria) throws IOException {
         this.initialization();
         // HERE: processing request. need update to & get values from this.hashtableResult
         this.hashtableResult  = null;
    }
}
```

If 2 sessions S1 et S2 request the stat on the same moment => the values of StatManagerImpl.hashtableResult is ok?

thanks a lot
best regards
dsea

Answer (score 0):

It will not be ok. Spring beans are by default Singleton. You should not store state in Spring benas. they should be stateless.

Comment: so i have to change all "privates" (like "hashtableResult") in the service (like StatManagerImpl) to local variables and passe them like the parameter of the method? thanks